# Unable to create managed bean

Tags: java, aplicação-web

Estou com um problema aqui na java que não sei como resolver nem o que pode ser porque estou a aprender a programar com o java para a web e nao conheço as possiveis causas do seguinte erro 
`javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to create managed bean testeHibernate`.

Codigo utilizado

testeHibernate.java

```
import java.util.List;

 import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
 import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
 import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
 import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
 import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
 import Classhiber.Utilizador;
 import DAO.UtilizadorDAO;
 @ManagedBean(name = "testeHibernate" )
 @SessionScoped
 public class testeHibernate {

private UtilizadorDAO utdao;

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{utiliza}")  
private Utilizador utiliza = new Utilizador();

public UtilizadorDAO getUtilizadorDAO() {
    return utdao;
}

public void setutilizador(UtilizadorDAO ut) {
    this.utdao = ut;
}

public Utilizador getutilizador() {
    return utiliza;
}

public void setutilizador(Utilizador utz) {
    this.utiliza = utz;
}

public String register() {
    // Calling Business Service
    utdao.addutilizador(utiliza);
    // Add message
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, 
            new FacesMessage("The Employee "+this.utiliza.getUser()+" Is Registered Successfully"));
    return "";
}
}
```

Spring.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/xp" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>


<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>Classhiber.Utilizador</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="UtilizadorDAOimpl" class="Impl.UtilizadorDAOimpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Face-config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
</faces-config>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" metadata-complete="true">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

erro -> Acontece quando faço o run do projecto no Tomcat-v7

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to create managed bean testeHibernate.  The following problems were found:
     - Property utiliza for managed bean testeHibernate does not exist.  Check that appropriate getter and/or setter methods exist.
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Em que momento este erro ocorre? Poderia passar o erro todo?

Comment: ja editei o post .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A causa do erro é essa:

```
 - Property utiliza for managed bean testeHibernate does not exist. Check that appropriate getter and/or setter methods exist.
```

Você precisa de mudar o nome dos `getters/setters` da propriedade utiliza. Você possui os métodos `setutilizador` e `getutilizador` que seta/retorna o valor da propriedade utiliza. Troque o nome deles para `setUtiliza` e `getUtiliza`.

Sempre que for fazer um método get ou set... adote esse padrão:  setNomeDaVariável, começando com letra maiúscula apóis o set ou get. Outra coisa é o nome da classe começar com letra maiúscula.

Tente seguir os [padrões de nomenclatura](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) da Oracle para facilitar o desenvolvimento dos seus programas, bem como a manutenção e evolução dos mesmos.

**UPDATE:**

Isso está errado: `@ManagedProperty(value = "#{utiliza}")`
Deveria ser assim: `@ManagedProperty(value = "utiliza")`

O `value` que será o "nome" da propriedade você deve colocar apenas o nome dela ( que no caso é `"utiliza"` ). Essa maneira aqui `#{utiliza}` é apenas **a sintaxe usada pelo JSF** para acessar a propriedade definida no `ManagedBean`.

**Observações**

**1)**

Eu não vejo necessidade de usar o `@ManagedProperty` já que você não vai "mudar o nome da propriedade" de utiliza para outro nome. Anotando o Bean como `@ManagedBean` você já consegue acessar no JSF as propriedades dele **que possuem o método get** da seguinte forma `#{testeHibernate.nomeDaPropriedade}`. Inclusive se você **tem um método** `getSoma( )` **mas não tem uma propriedade soma** no seu Bean, se você acessar pelo JSF `#{testeHibernate.soma}` **ele chamará o método** `getSoma()`.

**2)**

`@ManagedBean(name = "testeHibernate" )` esse atributo `name` serve para **dar o nome para o seu Bean** que será acessado no JSF. Por padrão, **se você não coloca o parametro name, ele cria** o nome dele copiando o nome da classe e **colocando a primeira letra minúscula**. Basta colocar `@ManagedBean` para ele fazer isso. No seu caso ficaria `testeHibernate`. Assim, **não tem necessidade** de você colocar o atributo name, **apenas se você quiser deixar explícito o nome que ele receberá**, o que eu vejo como uma boa prática também.

Comment: Obg.  Agora da-me um erro assim `@14,61 value="#{testeHibernate.utiliza.user}": Target Unreachable, 'utiliza' returned nul`  . ão tenho sorte nenhuma :)

Comment: `@ManagedProperty(value = "#{utiliza}")` essa sintaxe ta errada, deveria ser `@ManagedProperty(value = "utiliza")`

Comment: obrigado se souber de mais algum erro em termos de codigo que eu esteja a fazer errado diga para eu aprender .Obrigado.

Comment: Obrigado a todos .  Desculpem perguntar outra vez mas isto de quem nao sabe e como quem não vé é verdade ,  eu ja procurei bue na net e nao consigo resolver este erro `Ago 27, 2015 8:34:56 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: #{testeHibernate.save}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{testeHibernate.save}: java.lang.NullPointerException` . Já me disseram que era por causa do UtilizadorDAO nao estar inicialidado mas eu tentei inicializar e da sempre o mesmo erro . Obrigado

Comment: Para investigar um nullPointer exception é preciso mais detalhes... se for o caso, abra outro tópico para isso. Mas a razão dele é sempre quando tentamos acessar uma propriedade/método de um objeto que está nulo... você precisa acompanhar a execução do programa com um debug para poder descobrir onde está o problema